# Can ARCore track moving surfaces?

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

ARCore can track static surfaces according to its documentation, but doesn't mention anything about moving surfaces, so I'm wondering if ARCore can track flat surfaces (of course, with enough feature points) that can move around.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you definitely **can track moving surfaces and moving objects** in `ARCore`.

If you track static surface using `ARCore` – the resulted features are mainly suitable for so-called `Camera Tracking`. If you track moving object/surface – the resulted features are mostly suitable for `Object Tracking`.

You also can mask moving/not-moving parts of the image and, of course, inverse Six-Degrees-Of-Freedom (translate `xyz` and rotate `xyz`) camera transform.

> Watch [this video](https://www.reddit.com/r/oculus/comments/70tz8p/instead_of_tracking_the_static_environment_in/) to find out how they succeeded.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is the same thing but, Google says: "ARCore cannot track a moving image, but it can resume tracking that image after it stops moving."

Source: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/augmented-images/

Comment: You can use "Camera Tracking" principle for static environment to get an animated virtual camera for inserting 3D objects where real objects are, or you can use "Object Tracking" principle for dynamic objects to get an object's motion in 3D space. It's up to you what principle you'll choose. But one important thing is: you are able to invert a virtual camera's transform (6DOF) back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ARCore tracks feature points, estimates surfaces, and also allows access to the image data from the camera, so custom computer vision algorithms can be written as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be possible theoretically.

However, Ive tested it with some stuff in my HOUSE (running S8 and an app with unity and arcore) 
and the problem is more or less that it refuses to even start tracking movable things like books and plates etc:

due to the feature points of the surrounding floor etc it always picks up on those first.

Edit: did some more testing and i Managed to get it to track a bed sheet, it does However not adjust to any movement. Meaning as of now the plane stays fixed allthough i saw some wobbling but i guess that Was because it tried to adjust the Positioning of the plane once it's original Feature points where moved.